# list insert Iterator outside of range error

Tags: c++

I have this function

```
void Deck::draw(Hand &hand)
{
int random = (rand() % deckCards.size()) + 1;
list<Card*>::iterator cardID = deckCards.begin();

for (int i = 1; i < random; i++) {
    cardID++;
}

Card* selected = *cardID;

deckCards.erase(cardID);

hand.getHandCards().insert(hand.getHandCards().end(), selected);
}
```

with the following getter

```
list<Card*> Hand::getHandCards() const
{
return handCards;
}
```

and I get this error in the run time

[image]

Comment: what do you think happens when you get the maximum result of `int random = (rand() % deckCards.size()) + 1;` ?

Comment: Your function, `list<Card*> Hand::getHandCards()` returns a copy of the list, not a reference. You call it twice, there are two copies of the list created, and the iterators from each are not related.

Comment: I have a random number equal or less to the deck size.@idclev463035818

Comment: The card number is `[1,decksize]` which means you'll never pick the first card and sometimes pick a card out of bounds. You want `[0,decksize)`

Comment: @RetiredNinja I know I should return & of the list but in the return statement I don't know why I get error!!!

Comment: @TedLyngmo I never reach that number. Please, check the loop condition.

Comment: @EbraheemAlshapi Erhm... my bad. Why not `int random = rand() % (deckCards.size() + 1);` to let all cards be available? Btw, you should use [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) to not let me (or anyone else) make mistakes like that :-)

Comment: Why do you use pointers for this? A card is either in the deck or in someones hand or possibly on the table somewhere. Just move the card from one container to the next when it needs to move.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function returns a copy of `handCards`

```
list<Card*> Hand::getHandCards() const
{
    return handCards;
}
```

So, below

- one temporary copy is created and you pick its `end()` iterator.
- another temporary copy is created and you use the `end()` iterator from the other copy to insert.

```
hand.getHandCards().insert(hand.getHandCards().end(), selected);
```

This makes the program have undefined behavior and even *if* it would have been legal, both copies are temporary and will be destroyed at the end of the statement.

Without seeing the rest of the code it's hard to see if this is the only place you do things like this, but to fix this particular function, you should return a reference to the `handCards` variable:

```
list<Card*>& Hand::getHandCards()
{
    return handCards;
}
```

Thinking a bit further about it: You have a member function returning, what I presume is, a `private` member variable, letting everyone do what they please with it. Why not make it `public`? If you don't like that idea, add member functions to `Hand` that lets the user of the class do only those things you allow.

Example:

```
void Hand::insert(Card* card) {
    handCards.emplace_back(card);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. when I do the reference return I see this C++ qualifiers dropped in binding reference of type to initializer of type

Comment: You mean the `const` qualifier? Yes, I dropped that, so drop that in the class definition too. You are returning a non-`const` reference to `handCards` (to be able to make changes to it) so making `getHandCards()` `const` seemed pointless.

Comment: If you use `getHandCards()` in `const` contexts too, add a `const` overload for it, like `const list<Card*>& Hand::getHandCards() const`

Answer (score 2):

An iterator is only valid for one container. Your iterator is for different container, so it cannot be used to insert element into another.

Comment: @TedLyngmo The problem is with insert, not the erase (which I initially wrote).